# How can I hide header component in Login page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a global header component inside my router. But I want to hide on the login page.

I tried to use window.location solution like this. It works but doesn't work after the login page navigates to the homepage. (it doesn't show header till I refresh the page)

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./sass/app.scss";
import { db, auth } from "./configs/firebase-config";
import { MainContext } from "./hooks/Context";
import { eventbriteRoutes } from "./configs/routes";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Home/Header";

function App() {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(localStorage.getItem("isAuth"));

  const data = {
    isAuth,
    setIsAuth,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MainContext.Provider value={data}>
        <Router>
          {window.location.pathname !== "/login" ? <Header /> : null}{" "}
          <Routes>
            {eventbriteRoutes.map((RouteItem, index) => (
              <Route
                exact
                key={index}
                path={RouteItem.path}
                element={RouteItem.element}
              />
            ))}
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </MainContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a layout route that renders (*conditionally*) the `Header` component and an `Outlet` component for the nested route components.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = ({ hideHeaderPaths = [] }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  return (
    <>
      {!hideHeaderPaths.includes(pathname) && <Header />}
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}
```

...

```
function App() {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(localStorage.getItem("isAuth"));

  const data = {
    isAuth,
    setIsAuth,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MainContext.Provider value={data}>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route element={<Layout hideHeaderPaths={["/login"]} />}>
              {eventbriteRoutes.map((RouteItem) => (
                <Route
                  key={RouteItem.path}
                  path={RouteItem.path}
                  element={RouteItem.element}
                />
              ))}
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </MainContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Or if it's easier to just separate the `"/login"` route you can just create a layout route that unconditionally renders the `Header` component and render the login route separately.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const HeaderLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

...

```
function App() {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(localStorage.getItem("isAuth"));

  const data = {
    isAuth,
    setIsAuth,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MainContext.Provider value={data}>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route element={<HeaderLayout} />}>
              {eventbriteRoutes.map((RouteItem) => (
                <Route
                  key={RouteItem.path}
                  path={RouteItem.path}
                  element={RouteItem.element}
                />
              ))}
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </MainContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could potentially just remove it from the app.js and include it on the pages you want for it to be on. Or add class to make it display none based on the route